# Create Apollo-Server with Federated schema

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I am trying to create an Apollo-Server with a Federated Schema of TypeDefs loaded from a GraphQL file. However, I am getting this error

> `Argument of type 'GraphQLSchema' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | TemplateStringsArray'.`

I believe that I am loading the schema from the file with the wrong function `loadSchema`.
How can I load the schema from the file with the correct type to feed it as TypeDefs for the Federated Schema?

```
import { buildSubgraphSchema } from '@apollo/federation';
import { CodeFileLoader } from '@graphql-tools/code-file-loader';
import { loadSchema } from '@graphql-tools/load';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
...

const typeDefs = await loadSchema(`${__dirname}/auth.graphql`, {
  loaders: [new CodeFileLoader()],
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
 schema: buildSubgraphSchema([
     {
        typeDefs: gql(typeDefs),    // Error here `typeDefs`
        resolvers,
     }
  ]),
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also loading the subgraph schema from file and do it like this:

```
import { parse } from "graphql";
import { ApolloGateway } from "@apollo/gateway";
import * as fs from "fs";

const sdlStringFromFile = fs.readFileSync(
        `${__dirname}/auth.graphql`
    );

new ApolloGateway({
  localServiceList: [{
    name: "ServiceA",
    url: "https://servicea.com/graphql",
    typeDefs: parse(sdlStringFromFile)
  }]
})
```

Comment: Is this way the best practice to upload the subgraphs?

Comment: @HazemAlabiad if you were to ask Apollo for best practice I expect their answer would be to use Apollo Managed Federation and have the Apollo server load the schema from the registry at runtime.

Comment: How about if I want to print or output the federated single, federated, composed schema into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the `gql` function. The schema has already been parsed.

```
import { buildSubgraphSchema } from '@apollo/federation';
import { CodeFileLoader } from '@graphql-tools/code-file-loader';
import { loadSchema } from '@graphql-tools/load';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
...

const typeDefs = await loadSchema(`${__dirname}/auth.graphql`, {
  loaders: [new CodeFileLoader()],
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
 schema: buildSubgraphSchema([
     {
        typeDefs: typeDefs,
        resolvers,
     }
  ]),
})
```

Comment: When I remove the `gql` function, I mm getting another error `Type 'GraphQLSchema' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentNode': kind, definitionsts(2739)`

Comment: I believe that `buildSubgraphSchema` is expecting the `typeDefs` to be of type `DocumentNode`. So, I guess that we either need to use the correct function when loading or convert `graphqlschema` to `documentnode`